# WIX project Radio button value usage

Tags: wix

I am new to wix project and creating my first project. I want to install some features based on user selection. So I want to include radio buttons for user options. But when i include radio buttons, I dont understand how to know which radio button has been selected. And based on that selection value only I can proceed my installation.

Some how i got an idea to include publish events, but I dont know how to use that event

My sample code is,

```
<Property Id="RADIOBUTTONPROPERTY" Value="0"/>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<UI>
    <!--<Property Id="DefaultUIFont">DlgFont8</Property>-->
    <Dialog Id="InstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes" SystemModal="yes" >
    <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" Property="RADIOBUTTONPROPERTY" X="50" Y="10" Width="200" Height="25" Default="no" Text="Select your installation type"/>
    <Control Id="Install" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="RADIOBUTTONPROPERTY" X="50" Y="25" Width="200" Height="300" Default="yes">
                    
<!--Check button values here:-->
<Publish Event="Select1" Value="feature_dir_root1">RootType = 1</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select2" Value="feature_dir_root2">RootType = 2</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select3" Value="feature_dir_root3">RootType = 3</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select4" Value="feature_dir_root4">RootType = 4</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select5" Value="feature_dir_root5">RootType = 5</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select6" Value="feature_dir_root6">RootType = 6</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select7" Value="feature_dir_root7">RootType = 7</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select8" Value="feature_dir_root8">RootType = 8</Publish>
<Publish Event="Select9" Value="feature_dir_root9">RootType = 9</Publish>
<Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
</Control>
<Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"   Text="Ok" Cancel="yes" >
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"/>
</Control>
</Dialog>
<TextStyle Id="DlgFont8" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
<RadioButtonGroup Property="RADIOBUTTONPROPERTY">
    <RadioButton Value="0" X="100" Y="10" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Full Install" />
    <RadioButton Value="1" X="100" Y="30" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Logging DB Only" />
    <RadioButton Value="2" X="100" Y="50" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Patient DB only" />
    <RadioButton Value="3" X="100" Y="70" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Upgrade Logging DB" />
        <RadioButton Value="4" X="100" Y="90" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Recreate Logging DB" />
    <RadioButton Value="5" X="100" Y="110" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Upgrade Patient DB" />
    <RadioButton Value="6" X="100" Y="130" Width="600" Height="17" Text="Recreate Patient DB" />
</RadioButtonGroup>
InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="InstallDlg" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>
</UI>
```